# Save location data api in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, location

I was querying a system without my application, where the location data of the devices were updated at all times and sent to the firebase, searching for what is an API Location has this function, but how can I send the captured data to it and send it to Firebase ??? Anyone already work with something sign ???

Answer (score 0):

Make one child node using your device ID and set your latitude and longitude here, you need to make one model class

```
    class Model{
     public double lat;
     public double lng;
    } 

    Mpdel m = new Model();
    m.lat = 23.14578;
    m.lng = 72.45789;
    mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).setValue(m);
```

for update value of latitude and longitude you can write like,

```
mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).child("lat").setValue(<New_Value>);
mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).child("lng").setValue(<New_Value>);
```

here userid is your device id or any other unique elements.